# Skipping Escape Sequence Characters Python Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I was scraping a website but I am getting escape sequence characters with the output. The characters are the following:

> `\r \n \t \xa`

I tried .split() method but the issue with this method is when scrapy crawler doesn't find a single value, it doesn't scrape any value and move to the next iteration.

What's the best way to bypass these characters?

Following is the output:

[image]

Comment: try [`strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) not ``split``

Answer (score 1):

Python's [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) can achieve this.

```py
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', "\t \xa0")
' '
>>> re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', "\t \xa0 py \t \t \xa0 thon")
' py thon'
>>> # You can then use str.strip to get rid of any surrounding spaces
>>> re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', "\t \xa0 py \t \t \xa0 thon").strip()
'py thon'
```